# CSS hover over image and text

Tags: css, hover

I have squares with text on a website homepage and I want to add hover effect but dont know which class to choose from my website
www.justtobe.com.au homepage

the first big grid image ( beach photo), I want to add a hover effect  similar to this homepage grid

```
<h2 id="demo12">12. Opacity #2</h2>
<div class="hover12 column">
<div>
    <figure><img src="https://nxworld.net/example/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg" /></figure>
    <span>Hover</span>
</div>
<div>


/* Opacity #2 */



.hover
figure {
background: #1abc9c;
}
.hover12 figure img {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hover12 figure:hover img {
opacity: .5;
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can use the chrome inspector to work out which element you need to style

Comment: I tried and there are a lot of classes. I found this one "intrinsic" and it didnt work after I tried to modify the code

Comment: Your website is password protected

Comment: can try now and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you have to change if your picture to look the same as the one in the website you mentioned, but if you only want that hover effect then you just need to target the `span`

```
.hover12  span {
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 transition: .3s ease-in-out;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.hover12 span:hover {
 opacity: .5;
 display:block;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fhntLpmz/

Though, if you want it to look like the one in the website you mentioned, you need to change the structure of your html and then your css code.

```
<h2 id="demo12">12. Opacity #2</h2>
<div class="hover12 column">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span>Hover</span>
    </div>
<div>
```

Instead of using `img` to show the image, I use css to put it as a background, so that the **Hover** button is inside it.

```
.wrapper {
    background-image:url(https://nxworld.net/example/css-image-hover-effects/pic01.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
```

Other than this, it's just another couple of css. Take this example: https://jsfiddle.net/0shmd21e/1/

There are multiple ways to do this, though. This is just one of them

Comment: Thank you so much. I will use advice and give the wrapper one a go and see if it works.

Comment: My purpose is to create just a nice hover effect when someone goes over the whole image and text just like the button does now on just to be homepage.

Comment: if you want your image to have this effect, then you need to change the code a little. Instead of the `.wrapper` to have the `background-image` css, put it on something else. Like this https://jsfiddle.net/0shmd21e/2/